# What does 「たまらん」 mean?

Tags: translation, words

Just found a book and read the synopsis:

> 余命一週間と宣告された“たまらん”こと玉木走太

Is this equivalent in meaning to 洒落にならない?

Answer (score 5):

In this particular case, たまらん is his nickname. たま comes from his surname 玉木(**たま**き), and らん is "**run**" which comes from his given name **走**太(そうた). Of course, it's a pun for 堪らん = [堪らない](http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%9F%E3%81%BE%E3%82%89%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84).

Comment: +1 です。「こと」の説明があれば更に良かったと思います。

Comment: 「こと」= "a.k.a." とかでどうですか？

Comment: Note that the word before こと is *always* a nickname, title, or catchphrase of something/someone, and the word after こと is *always* its official name. If I'm not mistaken, English "a.k.a." is more loose (e.g. it can be used to give an alternative official name for something).